# Django create new instance of model with '__init__' function from table, instance data is error?

Tags: python, django, orm

there is my model code which have problem：

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url = models.URLField()
    card_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __init__(self, name, card_id, url, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.card_id = card_id
        self.url = url

    def __str__(self):
        return str({
            'name': self.name,
            'card_id': self.card_id,
            'url': self.url
        })
```

there is test code:

```
class PersonTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Person.objects.create(name="test",
                          card_id="123",
                          url="http://www.baidu.com")

    def test_get(self):
        p = Person.objects.get(name="test")
        print(p)
```

the print of test function 'test_get' is:

```
{'name': 1, 'card_id': 'test', 'url': '123'}
```

which is error.

the value of `name` is data of `id` column in table ,
the value of `card_id` is data of `name` column in table,
...

but if I change function `__init__` to follow:

```
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None, card_id=None, url=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

or delete function `__init__`, get the print of function `test_get` is:

```
{'name': 'test', 'card_id': '123', 'url': 'http://www.baidu.com'}
```

which is right.

In somewhere, I use `Person(....)` to create new instance, if I delete `__init__`, it means I cannot use `Person(...)` to create new instance,
Shall I change my code？

So what is best way to create new instance from table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not define `__init__` on a model at all. The base class - which you call via `super` - already sets attributes from kwargs. Remove that method.

Comment: In somewhere, I use `Person(....)` to create new instance, if I delete `__init__`, it means I cannot use `Person(...)` to create new instance.

Comment: @freeezeking You can, why not...it creates an instance that is not persistent in the DB

Comment: @freeezeking I *literally* said you can because the base class does this for you. **Remove that method**.

Comment: @freeezeking actually there is already an `__init__` method in your model, look at your code what do you think `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` does? Check answer below.

Comment: Is there other way that I can use `Person.objects.create` and `Person(...)` two function except what I have said?

Comment: Argh. Yes there is a way: by removing the method you have defined. Then `Person(...)` **will work fine**.

Answer (score 1):

> So what is best way to create new instance from table data?

You had it, the best way is to use `MyModel.objects.create` which will handle all the arguments, automatically set the primary key and return the instance.

The second way is:

```
my_model = MyModel(...)
my_model.save()
```

**If you want to know the problem with your test**

It's the instance attribute you are defining, such as `self.name = name`. When you assign the first argument to it you are actually assigning the `id` (which is passed by Django ORM behind the scene to the original `__init__`)

**Moral of the story**

Don't reinvent the wheel, those attributes are already set by Django.